# C# dynamically add text to tabcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, textbox

Having a slight problem on C#, still quite new to the language but hoping you can help. I have a program which dynamically creates tab forms and then I'm trying to add controls to the tabform (text boxes and labels), but no matter what I try it just doesn't seem to want to work. Here's the code I'm currently using (just to get one textbox in each form):

```
int i = dogresults;
while (i > 0)
{
    i--;
    DataRow dogrow = ds1.Tables["confirmdogs"].Rows[i];
    string dogname = dogrow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
    TabPage newpage = new TabPage(dogname);
    tcNewCustomer.TabPages.Add(dogname);

    TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
    tb1.Location = new Point(20, 10);
    newpage.Controls.Add(tb1);
    tb1.Name = "txtDogNo" + i;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer - it's a simple little typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Doh! Got it!**

You're not adding the new TabPage you're creating. This line:

```
tcNewCustomer.TabPages.Add(dogname);
```

should be like this:

```
tcNewCustomer.TabPages.Add(newpage);
```

(A small test app shows the tab pages being created without any textboxes with the first version, but with the second version working fine.)

---

That looks okay at a glance (although I haven't tried it - a short but complete demo program would help). When you say it "just doesn't seem to want to work" - what exactly is happening?

Have you tried moving the location down a bit? I know some controls are odd in terms of where their logical "top" is (i.e. it's not the first visible pixel).

Comment: As I'm guessing you assumed, it simply isn't visible. Tried moving the x,y co-ords inside the location point, but still nothing.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to reproduce it.

Comment: Oh goodness me, what a silly mistake that was! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the text in the textbox? Currently you're just setting the name...

Although I'd still expect you to see a border on the box + background colour assuming that differs from the tabpage background.

Comment: Just given that a try but it's still not visible